# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Execute Maintenance Plan from Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Maintenance Plan for Database Backups and some stuff in SQL SERVER 2008 R2.
Is there any possibility to execute this Maintenance Plan from PowerShell?

Thank you!
Sebastian

Comment: If this is something for which SQL API support is there, yes then you can do by assembly loading of the same APIs in PowerShell.

Comment: Are you talking about maintenance plan created through SSMS? In which case it's just an SSIS package. Typically a maintenance plan also creates a SQL Agent job. You could exec the SSIS package or start the SQL agent job. What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

If this is something for which SQL API support is there, yes then you can do by assembly loading of the same APIs in PowerShell.